# A função que estou chamando nao aparece, o que tem de errado?

Tags: javascript, html5

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
        <script src="mostrarCreditos.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Créditos</title>
        <input onclick="paraMenu()" type="button" value="ok" />

</head>
<body onload="creditosfinal()">
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function creditosfinal(){
    var nome1 = prompt("Antonio Lucas Rodrigues Franceschini RA: 15688724");
    var nome2 = prompt("Lucas Oliveira Dos Santos RA: 15677735");

    document.write(+ nome1 + "<br/>" + nome2 +);

    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode("OK");
    btn.onclick = paraMenu;
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}

function paraMenu()
{
    window.location.href = "menu.html";
}
```

Comment: Boa tarde , voce poderia postar o restante do codigo ?

Comment: Não entendi por que você usa prompt.

Comment: Boa tarde , retire os + nesse trecho  document.write(+ nome1 + "<br/>" + nome2 +) , ficando assim :  document.write(nome1 + "<br/>" + nome2);       Segue exemplo -> https://jsfiddle.net/h_felix/1r194c6L/

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, tomei a liberdade de ajustar algumas coisas em seu script, espero que possa acrescentar em sua aplicação.

```js
// Adiciona um evento ao document para quando a pagina estiver carregada. Substitui o onload.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', creditosFinal());

// Função que ao carregar a pagina cria os elementos no Body.
function creditosFinal() {
    var nome1 = 'Prompt não funciona aqui.'//prompt('Antonio Lucas Rodrigues Franceschini RA: 15688724');
    var nome2 = 'Prompt não funciona aqui.'//prompt('Lucas Oliveira Dos Santos RA: 15677735');
    
    document.body.appendChild(pNome(nome1,'p'));
    document.body.appendChild(pNome(nome2,'p'));
    document.body.appendChild(pNome('OK','button', 'click', paraMenu));
}

// Esta função retorna um novo elemento HTML.
function pNome(text, tipo, event, fn) {
    var elem = document.createElement(tipo);
    elem.textContent = text;
    if(event && fn) {
         elem.addEventListener(event, fn);
    }
    return elem;
}

// Função de redirecionamento.
function paraMenu() {
    // Redireciona para o menu.
    console.log('evento');
}
```

> Veja funcionando no
>   [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devgaspa/Lum1f6ok/)

Uma observação é que elementos visuais devem ser declarados dentro da tag `<body>` como por exemplo o `<input>` que foi declarado no `<header>`.

Answer (score 0):

`windows.location.href` não é um metodo, e sim uma propriedade que vai te dizer qual a URL atual do navegador e trocar o valor dessa propriedade vai redirecionar a pagina.

`window.open()` é um metodo que você cosegue passar a URL que você quiser para abrir uma nova aba, por exemplo;

**window.location.href exemplo:**

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com". // Vai te redirecionar para o google"
```

**window.open() exemplo:**

```
window.open('http://www.google.com'); // Vai abrir o google em uma nova janela..
```

Informações adicionais:

window.open() pode ser passado como parametro adicional, Veja: [window.open tutorial](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)

créditos: [Traduzido do topico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript)